# Is there a way to specify a URI other than localhost for webbit?

Tags: android, embeddedwebserver

So I am trying to create a server in an android application onto a remote URI and tried to do this using the createWebServer(), but it seems like this doesn't work because I cannot access the address on my computer.

```
server = WebServers.createWebServer(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), new InetSocketAddress(HOSTNAME,PORT), URI.create(HOSTNAME + ":" + PORT));
```

Does anyone know how to do this using Webbit?

Comment: can you access the server from the phone itself?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to check that since my app doesn't browse the internet after creating the server. But when I create a localhost server I must forward the tcp port using adb to access it from my PC browser. So I am wondering if webbit is just not capable of creating a remote server? I have tried using nanohttpd and it does this task fine but I would like to do this using Webbit

Comment: well you could try to issue a HTTP GET request to the web server you have just created in the app, and if it works, you'll know that the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: Yeah it doesn't seem to work